# How to place button below another in Eclipse Master Details Block?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have currently the following [Master Details Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS9en.png). The problem is that I want to place the `Button2` directly below `Button1`.

I have modified the code from this [tutorial](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html).

Here is my code:

```
protected void createMasterPart(final IManagedForm managedForm,
        Composite parent) {
    FormToolkit toolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
    Section section = toolkit.createSection(parent, Section.DESCRIPTION|Section.TITLE_BAR);
    section.setText("Test"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    section.setDescription("Test"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    section.marginWidth = 10;
    section.marginHeight = 5;
    Composite client = toolkit.createComposite(section, SWT.WRAP);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    layout.marginWidth = 2;
    layout.marginHeight = 2;
    client.setLayout(layout);
    Table t = toolkit.createTable(client, SWT.NULL);
    GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    gd.heightHint = 20;
    gd.widthHint = 100;
    t.setLayoutData(gd);
    toolkit.paintBordersFor(client);
    Button button1 = toolkit.createButton(client, "Button 1", SWT.PUSH); //$NON-NLS-1$
    gd = new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
    button1.setLayoutData(gd);
    Button button2 = toolkit.createButton(client, "Button 2", SWT.PUSH); //$NON-NLS-1$
    gd = new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
    button2.setLayoutData(gd);
    section.setClient(client);
    final SectionPart spart = new SectionPart(section);
    managedForm.addPart(spart);
    TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(t);
    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            managedForm.fireSelectionChanged(spart, event.getSelection());
        }
    });
    viewer.setContentProvider(new MasterContentProvider());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new MasterLabelProvider());
    viewer.setInput(page.getEditor().getEditorInput());
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: With is `client`? What layout is `client` using?

Comment: You need to show more than that, show the whole method.

Comment: @greg-449 I am sorry. I have added the complete method now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two columns the layout is currently putting the Table in the first row of the left column and then the first button in the right column. The second button is going in the left column of a new row.

To get the buttons to go in the right column you need to create an additional `Composite` to hold the two (or more) buttons:

```
Composite buttComposite = toolkit.createComposite(client, SWT.NONE);
buttComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
buttComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, false, false));

Button button1 = toolkit.createButton(buttComposite, "Button 1", SWT.PUSH); 
gd = new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
button1.setLayoutData(gd);
Button button2 = toolkit.createButton(buttComposite, "Button 2", SWT.PUSH); 
gd = new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
button2.setLayoutData(gd);
```